# Upload only one file per each directory using blueimp file upload

Tags: file-upload, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

I have encountered one boring problem  when working with blueimp file upload. The problem is:
I have carousel in my web site. Each Image has its own Title, Description and other details stored in database. But I have not stored the image's url in database table. The images are stored in a seperate directory as :

```
carousels <root dir>
   |
   +---- {carousel_id} <dir> 
   |   |___ image 1 <image file 1>
   |
   +---- {carousel_id} <dir>
       |___ image 1 < image file 1>
       |___ image 2 <image file 2> # Which I do not want
```

I want only one file (image for now) per each directory.

What I am doing now is , First I fetch all the carousels from the database table and find out the related image using the carousel_id (which is auto-increment primary key in database table). But if there are multiple files in some directory (say in dir "1") I am currently selecting one image file randomly. And what I know is each carousel can have only one image.

**In very short:

How can I delete other files from the directory when I upload a single file to the same directory successfully using blueimp jquery file-upload.**

I am using PHP in server side.

Please Help me.
Thankyou.

Comment: which language do you use on the server side?

Comment: I am using php on the server side.